# Anyway to hack a portable AC unit to cool 2 rooms

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

I am looking to take a portable AC unit and hopefully run a tube through a wall in another room while still cooling the room the unit is located. I have searched to attachments that could help but have come up empty. Any help would be appreciated.

DR

Comment: In my experience with a portable A/C unit, the cooling power was so anemic that it couldn't even cool one room, let alone two.

Answer (score 4):

Any way of circulating the air between the rooms will help, although I doubt you will be able to achieve uniform temperatures. Put the AC in the room that is hotter (e.g. has more windows) and then do the best you can with a fan or two.

Also, make sure the AC is properly sized for the area you want to cool.